# get value in php from js function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mqtt

I am confused that how to get data from js to php variable.In JS function, I am getting data frequently on event.The problem is I want to get data in php frequently because it is real time data.`payload` contains the data whenever the data comes.So I have to get value of `payload` continuously.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>
    function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;   
    };
     var mqtt,payload;
     var value = 10;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
    function MQTTconnect() {
    if (typeof path == "undefined") {
        path = '/mqtt';
    }
    mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
            'broker',
            1883,
             "/mqtt",
            "a:" + "abcdef" + ":" + Date.now()
    );
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            useSSL: false,
            cleanSession: true,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: function (message) {
                $('#status').val("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage + "Retrying");
                setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
            }
        };

        mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;


        options.userName = 'user';
        options.password = 'password';


        mqtt.connect(options);

    }

    function onConnect() {
        document.writeln("connected");

        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
        mqtt.subscribe('iot-2/type/+/id/+/evt/evt1/fmt', {qos: 0});
        //$('#topic').val('iot-2/type/" + "+" + "/id/" + "+" + "/evt/evt1/fmt');

    }

    function onConnectionLost(response) {
        setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
        //$('#status').val("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage + ". Reconnecting");

    };

    function onMessageArrived(message) {

        var topic = message.destinationName;
         payload = message.payloadString;  

        //document.writeln(payload);
        //document.write("\n"); 
        //$('#ws').prepend('<li>' + topic + ' = ' + payload + '</li>');

    };
    </script>


</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $db = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(MQTTconnect());</script>';
        $db1 = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(payload);</script>';
        echo $db;
        echo $db1;      
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really do not think there's any other reliable way than to send the value to the server using most likely ajax call.

Comment: @DavidPacker can you suggest how to use ajax in this case..

Comment: I don't have time now, but you really shouldn't mix DOM manipulation with server side rendering. I'll post an answer later if nobody answers the question until then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'document.write(MQTTconnect());'
   , '</script>'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

the applicable way to get data in php frequently is to assign js data for an php element when it change .

for example  , when js function executed you can write

```
$("Element").val(output)// from js function 
, $("element").html(output) or
by document.getElementById(element) etc...`
```

So , any change will change the value of php element accordingly